# define realtion in eloquent orm based on third table

Tags: orm, laravel, relational-database, eloquent

i have 3 tables, how can i define relation between taxonomy and user based on contracts that bind them ?

```
Taxonomy  : tax_id,name
Users     : user_id,name
contracts : tax_id,user_id,start_time,end_time
```

SQL:
`SELECT * FROM taxonomy t where t.tax_id in(select tax_id from contracts where user_id = 3 and DATE() between Start_time and end_time)`

but how to define this relation in eloquent orm ?

Answer (score -1):

Define a many-to-many relationship between Taxonomy and Users with Contracts as the pivot table, more in the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships)

To access start_time and end_time you must specify them when defining the [relationship](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables), for example in the Taxonomy model:

```
class Taxonomy extends Eloquent {

  public function users()
  {
      return $this->belongsToMany('User')->withPivot('start_time', 'end_time');
  }

}
```

Comment: what about start_time and end_time condition ?, can you provide a code example to complete answer plz ?

Comment: I've updated the answer including the extra fields from the Taxonomy model, you should declare them also when specifing the relationship from users.